# Correlation of Fourier transforms of characteristic functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, additive-combinatorics

Let $A$ and $B$ ($A\subset B$) be subsets of a finite abelian group $G$. (For the sake of argument, you can take $G$ to be $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for large $p$, say.) Write $1_S$ for the characteristic function of any subset $S\subset G$. Put the counting measure on $G$ and $\widehat{G}$, so that, for
instance, $|1_S| = |S|$, where $|S|$ is the number of elements of $S$.
Normalize the Fourier transform on $G$ so that it is an isometry: $|\widehat{f}|_2 = |f|_2$.

What upper bounds can be given for the size of $|\widehat{1_A} \widehat{1_B}|_1$?

To be precise: Cauchy-Schwarz gives $|\widehat{1_A} \widehat{1_B}|_1\leq |\widehat{1_A}|_2 |\widehat{1_B}|_2 = |1_A|_2 |1_B|_2 = \sqrt{|A| |B|}$. On the other hand, $\left|\sum_x \widehat{1_A}(x) \widehat{1_B}(x)\right| = \left|\sum_g 1_A(g) 1_B(g)\right| = \left|\sum_g 1_A(g)\right| = |A|$, suggesting there might be some room for improvement.

So, the question could be made more pointed, as follows: if $|\widehat{1_A} \widehat{1_B}|_1$ is closer to $\sqrt{|A| |B|}$ than to $|A|$, what follows about $|A|$ and $|B|$? What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $|\widehat{1_A} \widehat{1_B}|_1$ to be bounded by a constant times $|A|$?

Comment: I should add that $|\widehat{1_A} \widehat{1_B}| = |A|$ holds for the extreme cases $B=A$ and $B=G$, as well as for any shift $B=A+g$.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of the uncertainty principle of Donoho and Stark.

Comment: It seems that the subscript $1$ is missing in $|1_S|$ and in $|\widehat{1_A}\widehat{1_B}|$ in your comment. Also, are you sure you are interested in the norm $|\widehat{1_A}\widehat{1_B}|_1$ and not in $|\widehat{1_A}\overline{\widehat{1_B}}|_1$? (For $\langle \hat f,\hat g\rangle=\langle f,g\rangle$ to hold, the scalar product is to be defined as $\sum_\chi \hat f(\chi)\overline{\hat g(\chi)}$.)

Comment: @Seva: In this case the $\ell^k$ norm of $\hat{f}$ is defined to be $(\sum_t |f(t)|^k)^{1/k}$, so it doesn't matter whether or not we include the complex conjugate - it will be removed by the absolute value.

Comment: @Eric Naslund: this is not my point. What I mean is that $\sum_x\widehat{1_A}(x)\widehat{1_B}(x)$ is *not* equal to $\sum_g 1_A(g)1_B(g)$, but to $\sum_g 1_A(g)1_{-B}(g)$. Therefore, I suspect that in the original question should refer to $\widehat{1_A}\overline{\widehat{1_B}}$ instead of $\widehat{1_A}\widehat{1_B}$. Agreed?

Comment: Yes, all norms are $\ell_1$-norms in my comment. Assume $A=-A$ and $B=-B$ for the sake of argument - but, at any rate, $|\sum_g 1_A(g) 1_{-B}(g)|\leq |A|$ even without that assumption.

Comment: Incidentally, I am aware that $|\widehat{1_A} \widehat{1_B}|_1 \sim \sqrt{|A| |B|}$ does hold sometimes. Let, for instance, $G = \mathbb{F}_p^{n+m}$; let $A\subset \mathbb{F}_p^n \times \{0\} \subset G$. Let $B$ be the union of $A+e_i$, where $i$ ranges from $n+1$ and $m$ (here $e_i$ denotes the $i$th basis vector of $\mathbb{F}_p^{n+m}$). Then $\widehat{1_B}$ behaves like $\widehat{1_A}$ times a factor equal to the sum of $m$ independent random variables, each of them taking as its value any $p$th root of unity with probability $1/p$.

Comment: What more could be said then $| \hat{1}_A \hat{1}_B|_1 = | 1_A 1_B|_1 = |A\cap B|$? You impose Fourier transform is unitary.

Comment: No, precisely - $\langle \widehat{1_A},\widehat{1_B}\rangle = \langle 1_A,1_B\rangle = |A\cap B|$, but the first equality in what you write need not be true...

Comment: Sorry, if am wrong. My confusion comes thinking too much about the real. You mean $\overline{ \hat{1}_B} \neq \hat{1}_B$, but this seems to be true if $B=-B$!? We have that $\hat{\hat{1_B}} = 1_{-B}$?